# How can I deal with this double.NaN

Tags: c#

I have the a `Convert.ToDecimal()` which occasionally throws an exception with the message

> Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal

, because the call to `DataContainer.GetValue(ColKeyId, index)` returns `double.NaN`.

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(DataContainer.GetValue(ColKeyId, index)) != Convert.ToDecimal(newValueToSet))
{
    DataContainer.SetValue(ColKeyId, index, newValueToSet);
}
```

I cannot change the API implementation call of the `GetValue()`.
What would be the best approach to deal with the conversion to decimal of a NaN double?

Comment: If you can, add `TryGetValue` which returns `bool` and `out`s result if possible to `DataContainer`. If this isn't possible too, go for `try` / `catch`

Comment: Well what do you *want* to happen when the result is NaN? The implementation will be fairly simple, but you need to work out what you want to do. (Note that you should think about positive and negative infinity, too...)

Comment: @Jon. When the result is NaN, I would like to be able and cal SetValue

Comment: @Alizera. I already have a try/catch. The exception is caught with the above message

Comment: @Nostradamus Check for `double.IsNan` and set an exception value? I mean you need to decide what to do, right?

Comment: What is the type of `newValueToSet`, and why are you converting to decimals at all?

Comment: @Jon. Thanks for your reply. newValueToSet is a double type. It is converted to decimal for comparison purposes.

Comment: @Nostradamus: But *why*? What kind of comparison are you trying to perform that requires this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so it sounds like you just need to detect whether or not it's a NaN value:

```
double value = DataContainer.GetValue(ColKeyId, index);
if (double.IsNaN(value) || double.IsInfinity(value) ||
    (decimal) value != (decimal) newValueToSet)
{
    DataContainer.SetValue(ColKeyId, index, newValueToSet);
}
```

To be honest, it's not clear why you're converting from `double` to `decimal` at all, but this code at least shows how you can detect NaN/infinite values. Note that I've changed the calls to `Convert.ToDecimal` to simple casts to make the code simpler - but you could use `Convert.ToDecimal` if you want, of course..

Comment: Jon, seems to me like `(decimal) value != (decimal) newValueToSet` is quite a strange check - if you get rounding errors (decimal is 128 bits, double is 64 bits), that will mess things up, right? Apart from that, this is what I had in mind as well...

Comment: @atlaste: Yes, I agree it's odd - but that's what's in the question. I haven't introduced the oddity, just changed its form from `Convert.ToDecimal` calls into casts.

Comment: Jon, true; just seemed to me like a good idea not to simply copy his bad practices, but instead explain what's wrong with it. :-) Anyways, let's just hope he picks up and understand my remark; you're answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal.TryParse

So then you will know if it converted or not and if not assigne a defasult value or branch off down some other avenue.

HTH

Comment: No because TryParse(String, Decimal). I have a double type which is converted to decimal. nothing to do with strings

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is `double.NaN` before setting:

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(DataContainer.GetValue(ColKeyId, index)))
{
    if (Convert.ToDecimal(DataContainer.GetValue(ColKeyId, index)) != Convert.ToDecimal(newValueToSet))
    {
        DataContainer.SetValue(ColKeyId, index, newValueToSet);
    }
}
```